# Sentences with (noun+adjective+preposition) structure

Tags: relative-pronouns, adjective-order

I found these two sentences 
**He is a man suitable for any post.
**The subject is a matter worthy of note.**
Why is there no relative pronoun and be verb between the noun and the adjective? What are the rules for forming this kind of sentences?  I am very much confused.  Kindly clear my doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking why they can be written that way, instead of "He is a man who is suitable for any post" and "The subject is a matter which is worthy of debate", right? Both forms of them are correct; the pronoun and be verb are optional. Writing them out in full is maybe a bit more formal, but they both mean the same thing.